# Cannot retrieve the id of the last inserted row in Hibernate using Oracle

Tags: oracle, spring, hibernate, jsp, oracle10g

I'm using Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA with the Spring version 3.0.2. I'm trying to retrieve the id of the last inserted row into the Oracle(10g) database as follows.

```
Session session=NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();

Country c=new Country();

c.setCountryId(new BigDecimal(0));
c.setCountryName(request.getParameter("txtCountryName"));
c.setCountryCode(request.getParameter("txtCountryCode"));
Zone z=(Zone) session.get(Zone.class, new BigDecimal(request.getParameter("zoneId")));
c.setZone(z);
session.save(c);

session.flush();    
System.out.println(c.getCountryId());    
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

This statement `System.out.println(c.getCountryId());` is expected to return the currently inserted id after the data is serialized to the database and before the transaction is committed but it doesn't because of the following line in the preceding code snippet (as it presumably appears to me).

```
c.setCountryId(new BigDecimal(0));
```

I'm not sure why this statement is required in my case (while inserting). I saw this statement nowhere. Omission of this line causes the following exception to be thrown.

> org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class
>   must be manually assigned before calling save(): model.Country

Is this statement `c.setCountryId(new BigDecimal(0));` really required during insertion? It's a sequence generated primary key in the Oracle database and because of that line, this statement `System.out.println(c.getCountryId());` always returns `0` which is actually expected to return the currently inserted id in the current session.

So, how can I get the last generated id in this case? Am I following a wrong way, is there a different way?

---

**EDIT:**

```
CREATE TABLE  "COUNTRY" 
(   
    "COUNTRY_ID" NUMBER(35,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COUNTRY_CODE" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "COUNTRY_NAME" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "ZONE_ID" NUMBER(35,0), 

    CONSTRAINT "COUNTRY_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("COUNTRY_ID") ENABLE, 
    CONSTRAINT "COUNTRY_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("ZONE_ID")
                            REFERENCES  "ZONE" ("ZONE_ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_COUNTRY" 
before insert on "COUNTRY"               
for each row  

begin   
    select "COUNTRY_SEQ".nextval into :NEW.COUNTRY_ID from dual; 
end; 

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "BI_COUNTRY" ENABLE
/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception 'ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()' means that you are using the identifier generation strategy of 'Assigned'.

> **assigned**
>   lets the application assign an identifier to the object before save() is called. This is the default strategy if no  element is specified.

If you do not define any strategy, hibernate defaults to 'assigned'. 'assigned' strategy implies that hibernate expects that the application supplies it's own ids.

If you want to use a sequence id generator in Oracle, you can do so with the following configuration -

If you are using xml -

```
   <id name="countryId" type="java.lang.Integer">  
        <column name="Country_Id" />  
        <generator class="sequence">  
            <param name="sequence">Country_Id_Seq</param>               
        </generator>  
    </id>
```

If you are using annotations -

```
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="Country_Id_Seq")
   @SequenceGenerator(name="Country_Id_Seq", sequenceName="Country_Id_Seq"  )
   private Integer sequence;
```

And your code should look like so -

```
Country c=new Country();

c.setCountryName(request.getParameter("txtCountryName"));
c.setCountryCode(request.getParameter("txtCountryCode"));
Zone z=(Zone) session.get(Zone.class, new BigDecimal(request.getParameter("zoneId")));
c.setZone(z);
session.save(c);

session.flush();    
System.out.println(c.getCountryId());
```

When 'session.save(c)' executes, hibernate makes the following sql call to Oracle, retrieves the id and sets it in Country object.

```
select Country_Id_Seq.nextVal from dual;
```

**Problem with trigger**

Since you are using a trigger to increment the id when a row is inserted, this will cause a problem with hibernate sequence. Hibernate is using the sequence to generate an id and the database is using the trigger to increment the id. This is resulting in the id being incremented twice.

You have a three options to resolve this.

1. Delete the trigger because it's not necessary.
2. If you still need the trigger because the table could be updated outside the application, you could update the trigger such that the id is generated only if the id is not set in the insert statement
   [HIbernate issue with Oracle Trigger for generating id from a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002119/hibernate-issue-with-oracle-trigger-for-generating-id-from-a-sequence)
3. Create a custom id generator that uses the trigger to set the id in the data before it is saved to db. Check out the following link - https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=973262

Comment: It throws this exception `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: this id generator generates long, integer, short or string`. I have already a `BigDecimal` mapping with the primary key. Is there a way to deal with a `BigDecimal` sequence?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. But you will have to create your own custom generator. It shouldn't be that difficult. But, I suggest that if it's not too much of a trouble, please change your id to 'Long'. Please read the solution in this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276839/oracle-hibernate-sequence-generator-problem

Comment: I have tried to change `BigDecimal` type to `long`. What happens is that `countryId` inserted into the database is `393` but it shows `392` through this statement `System.out.println(c.getCountryId());`. It appears that the sequence is executed twice. Why does it happen? Is it only generated by the front-end and do I need to drop the sequence from the Oracle table?

Comment: This shouldn't have happened. Hibernate is not creating it's own sequence. It is just using a sequence that was already created in the database. Do you have a trigger that sets 'Country_Id' just before it is inserted in to the database?

Comment: @Sashi- The only trigger associated with the `COUNTRY` table in the Oracle database is the one which was created by Oracle itself along with the sequence associated with the primary key column `COUNTRY_ID`. I didn't create any explicit trigger on my own, regarding the `COUNTRY` table. I don't realize why this happens.

Comment: I don't think oracle by default creates any trigger. Could you post your ddl for creating 'Country' table?

Comment: @Sashi- Edited the question to include the corresponding DDL statement   of the `COUNTRY` table, along with the trigger (it was created by Oracle itself when a sequence is associated with the primary key column `COUNTRY_ID`).

Comment: @Tiny Hibernate is using the sequence to generate an id and the database is using the trigger to increment the id. This is resulting in the id being incremented twice. You have a three options. 1. Delete the trigger because it's not necessary. 2. If you still need the trigger because the table could be updated outside the application, you could update the trigger such that the id is generated only if the id is not set in the insert statement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002119/hibernate-issue-with-oracle-trigger-for-generating-id-from-a-sequence.

Comment: The third option is - 3. Create a custom id generator that uses the trigger to set the id in the data before it is saved to db. https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=973262

Comment: @Shashi- I have just disabled (not yet dropped) the trigger and the operation successfully finished. Thank you very much for your effort and assistance for a long time. I would say just copy and past the contents of these two preceding comments in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13323165/1391249) question recently asked by me (these two comments have the expected answer) and I would hopefully accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If the values into an ID column generated by a sequence, then you should associate that sequence with your ID column in the entity definition so that the attribute is filled in with the ID value by Hibernate during insertion.

*Using annotations:*

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CountryIdSequence")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CountryIdSequence", sequenceName = "COUNTRY_ID_SEQUENCE")
@Column(name = "COUNTRY_ID")
private BigDecimal countryId;
```

*Using hbm:*

```
<id name="countryId" type="big_decimal">
    <column name="COUNTRY_ID" />
    <generator class=""sequence">
        <param name="sequence">COUNTRY_ID_SEQUENCE</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

Then, it will be available after the save.

Any changes made to the entity at the database layer are not reflected in the hibernate entity layer until you refresh the object.

```
session.save(c);
session.flush();    
// Refresh the object for columns modified in the DB by IDENTITY / SEQUENCE / Triggers.
session.refresh(c);
System.out.println(c.getCountryId());
```

Comment: I tried as you mentioned but unfortunately it threw this exception `org.hibernate.UnresolvableObjectException: No row with the given identifier exists: [model.Country#0]`, the *country id* 0 is obviously not expected and if I omit this line `c.setCountryId(new BigDecimal(0));` then, it again throws the exception as mentioned in the question. Additionally, I have XML mappings in the `xxx.hbm.xml` files like `Country.hbm.xml`.

Comment: In the `Country.hbm.xml` file, the `countryId` column is mapped like `<id name="countryId" type="big_decimal">
      <column name="COUNTRY_ID" precision="35" scale="0"/>
      <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>`

Comment: Can you try modifying the hbm.xml file as updated in the response?

Comment: I have tried to change `BigDecimal` type to `long`. What happens is that `countryId` inserted into the database is `393` but it shows `392` through this statement `System.out.println(c.getCountryId());`. It appears that the sequence is executed twice. Why does it happen? Is it only generated by the front-end and do I need to drop the sequence from the Oracle table? It happens when I remove this line `session.refresh(c);`. With that statement it throws an exception. By the way, the approach with `BigDecimal` doesn't seem to work in a straight forward way.

Comment: With this line `session.refresh(c);`, it throws this exception `org.hibernate.UnresolvableObjectException: No row with the given identifier exists: [model.Country#396]` because `countryId` inserted into the database is `397` but it retrieves `countryId` `396`.