# Oracle sequence for a primary key field doesn't retrieve the currently inserted value in Hibernate

Tags: oracle, spring, hibernate, jsp, oracle10g

I have the following code that attempts to fetch a generated sequence value for the primary key column `COUNTRY_ID` of the `COUNTRY` table in my Oracle (10g) database.

```
Country c=new Country();

c.setCountryName(request.getParameter("txtCountryName"));
c.setCountryCode(request.getParameter("txtCountryCode"));
Zone z=(Zone) session.get(Zone.class, new BigDecimal(request.getParameter("zoneId")));
c.setZone(z);
session.save(c);

session.flush();
//session.refresh(c);
System.out.println(c.getCountryId()); //Attempts to display the sequence value.
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

This statement `System.out.println(c.getCountryId());` in this codes attempts to display the currently generated sequence value after insertion is done.

Sequence generated values in the Oracle table are inserted <s>in multiple of 2 i.e</s>  something like this 414, 416, 418, 420... instead of being inserted them in a chain like 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420...

Suppose, the currently inserted sequence value in the Oracle table is `426`, this statement `System.out.println(c.getCountryId());` shows `425` (whereas in the `COUNTRY_ID` column in the Oracle table, the inserted value is `426`).

**Presumably, it appears that the sequence is executed twice for some reasons**.

---

In my Hibernate POJO, I have designated the `countryId` primary key column as follows,

```
@Id
@Column(name = "COUNTRY_ID")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CountryIdSequence", sequenceName = "COUNTRY_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CountryIdSequence")
private long countryId;
```

In the `Country.hbm.xml` mapping file, this column `countryId` is mapped as follows.

```
<id name="countryId" type="long">
  <column name="COUNTRY_ID" precision="35" scale="0"/>
  <generator class="sequence">
    <param name="sequence">COUNTRY_SEQ</param>
  </generator>
</id>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You either need the annotations or the hbm file, but not both. I can imagine that because both are present, it's confusing hibernate. And just to be 100% sure, are you saying that the `c.getCountryId()` is returning an id that doesn't exist in the DB, and hibernate has stored a row with a different id?

Comment: I already tried with either of these two but unfortunately, it didn't make any difference and yes the `c.getCountryId()` method is returning a value that doesn't exist in the table.

Comment: Then, you're not missing anything on this class. Very often Hibernate will fail in one place because there's a mapping error somewhere else. Try searching other classes that you've added and see if there's something odd/wrong there. Printing the sql statements might help you to find out what is going on (to see what operations are done before and after hibernate gets a value from the sequence).

Comment: If this line `//session.refresh(c);` in the first code snippet is uncommented then the operation ends with an exception `org.hibernate.UnresolvableObjectException: No row with the given identifier exists: [model.Country#427]` because the inserted id was `428` and not `427`.

Comment: Again, check the other mappings, the mapping you have for `Mapping.countryId` is correct.

Comment: I had indeed a trigger against the `COUNTRY` table automatically created by Oracle itself (Oracle GUI) to associate the sequence with the primary key column `COUNTRY_ID`. It's for this reason, the sequence was being executed twice once by Hibernate and again by the trigger. I disabled the trigger temporarily and the approach worked. This question was answered by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300808/?lq=1#comment18176090_13301412) comment after I had asked this question otherwise, there wouldn't have been a need to post this question. Sorry everyone for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I indeed had a trigger against the `COUNTRY` table which is automatically created by an Oracle GUI tool to associate the sequence with the primary key column `COUNTRY_ID`.

The sequence was being executed twice once by Hibernate and again by the trigger. I disabled the trigger temporarily and the approach worked as intended.