# How to save children of a table in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have three tables

Client, Relation, Status

Inside my `Client` Entity, I have

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "relationId")
private Relation relationId;
```

and

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "statusId")
private Status statusId;
```

The relation and status entities have just getter/setter, No relationships.

Here I'm saving/updating my client, and with this I want to save/create this relation as well

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

try
{

    Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
    updatedClient = (Client) session.get(Client.class, id);
    updatedClient.setClientPostCode(client.getClientPostCode());
    updatedClient.setRelationId(client.getRelationId());

    session.saveOrUpdate(client.getRelationId());
    session.update(updatedClient);
    tr.commit();
}
```

There's no exception in this code, `Client` is successfully saved, `Relation` is successfully created but  the `relationID` which was created is not assigning to the `relationID` column in the Client's table.

The relation which is created with this code has the `relationID`(primarykey:  3) 
but in the `relationId` column in `Client`, the value is being saved is always `0` which should actually be `3` in this case.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Isn't it possible to get the `relationId` after 
this line?

```
session.saveOrUpdate(client.getRelationId());
```

So that I can get the `relationId` without going to DB and simply save that Id in my `Client` table?

Comment: session.save(client.getRelationId());
   session.flush();                        tried here , but no luck !

Comment: `commit` flushes the session and ends the unit of work, if the flushmode is not set to manual [FlushMode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html)

Comment: yes , even after commit , i dont get the generated Id for any table ,as i am watching in debug

Comment: try calling `updatedClient.setRelationId(client.getRelationId());` after `session.saveOrUpdate(client.getRelationId());`

Comment: NO luck ! , did this way now    session.save(client.getRelationId());
session.flush();
updatedClient.setRelationId(client.getRelationId());
session.update(updatedClient);
tr.commit();

Comment: You'll have to deal with auto-increment values of the primary key column - `relationID`.You're trying to get the last inserted value of the primary key column (regarding the current session).Which database system are you using? If you're using Oracle then the `relationID` can be obtained if and only if it's a sequence generated primary key. Go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13300808/1037210) question carefully to see how to do this. If you have any trigger operating upon the primary key column then it will also cause problems.You will have to drop that trigger or at least disable it

Comment: i'm using my MySQL , how to deail in MySQL , and my relationId is set to auto increment

Comment: I can't remember correctly, since I used MySql with Hibernate, a time ago but presumably, you could replace `@Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="Country_Id_Seq")` as mentioned in the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13301412/1037210) of that question with `@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)`. Just go through it carefully. It uses `xxx.hbm.xml` mapping files but the annotation approach as with you is also described there.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm very glad to hear this. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try specifying the `cascade` parameter in your `@ManyToOne` annotation:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

It defaults to no cascaded operations.

Comment: @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "relationId")
 private Relation relationId;             : did this , But No Luck !