# Oracle DUAL table returns "no rows selected"

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g, sequence

I got this query:

```
insert into biller_onboarding_tbl values(BILLER_ONBOARDING_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,'1','blah','j', '1','dsad','das','dasd','dsad','dasd','dasd','dsadsa')

1 rows inserted.

select * from BILLER_ONBOARDING_TBL;
```

returns all rows -

```
select BILLER_ONBOARDING_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL from dual;

no rows selected
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Selecting from `dual` should always return a row, does `select * from dual` work as expected?!?

Comment: Yes, select * from dual also returning ''no rows selected".

Comment: Post result of `SELECT * FROM SYS.DUAL`. This would confirm whether `sys.dual` has been manipulated.

Answer (score 2):

> select BILLER_ONBOARDING_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL from dual;

It might be possible that the dual table is empty. With `SYSDB` privilege, you could **delete/truncate** the **SYS.DUAL** table.

However, you will still get the `sequence.nextval` value even if dual doesn't return any row. The **optimizer** is somehow sure to **always fetch a row** from the dual table.

```
SQL> conn sys@pdborcl as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> select * from dual;

D
-
X

SQL> delete from dual;

1 row deleted.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from dual;

no rows selected
```

So, there are **no rows** in the **dual table**.

Let's create a **sequence** and test:

```
SQL> create sequence s;

Sequence created.

SQL> select s.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1

SQL> select * from dual;

no rows selected

SQL> select s.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         2
```

The **explain plan** shows that the **FAST DUAL** operation still fetches a row:

```
SQL> explain plan for select s.nextval from dual;

Explained.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3499163060

-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SEQUENCE        | S    |       |            |          |
|   2 |   FAST DUAL      |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**NOTE** : **DUAL** is a special table which is owned by **SYS**. It is a part of the data dictionary. It is not a good idea to manipulate the data dictionary. It is not recommended.

If the dual table has not been manipulated, then you should be able to see the following output from **dba_objects**:

```
SQL> column owner format a15
SQL> column object_name format a15
SQL> column object_type format a15
SQL> SELECT owner, object_name, object_type FROM dba_objects WHERE object_name='DUAL';

OWNER           OBJECT_NAME     OBJECT_TYPE
--------------- --------------- ---------------
SYS             DUAL            TABLE
PUBLIC          DUAL            SYNONYM

SQL>
```

In your case, it might be that a custom table named DUAL has been created and which does not contain any row.

If that's the case, and that the SYS.DUAL has not been manipulated, then try using:

```
select BILLER_ONBOARDING_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL from SYS.dual;
```

Comment: I remember having fun decades ago by inserting a 2nd row. At least it's named DUAL :-)

Comment: Lalit, Thanks for your detail explaination. Actually , i need it for hibernate generated query , which is executed before "insert into". Following is the  query - "Hibernate: select BILLER_ONBOARDING_ID_SEQ.nextval from dual ", I have created another user which is passed to hibernate for doing it's transaction. so how would i execute this hibernate query as SYS.?

Comment: Post result of `SELECT * FROM SYS.DUAL`. This would confirm whether `sys.dual` has been manipulated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
select BILLER_ONBOARDING_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL from SYS.dual;
```

You have a *custom* table `DUAL` in your database. And hence, the *private synonym* might point your version of table, instead of `SYS.DUAL`.

So, Querying `DUAL` with the schema name `SYS`, will solve tht.

```
SELECT OWNER,TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'DUAL';
```

This query would list a table that *doesn't* reside in `SYS` schema.

**EDIT:**

From comments, we could infer that you look for

[Cannot retrieve the id of the last inserted row in Hibernate using Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300808/cannot-retrieve-the-id-of-the-last-inserted-row-in-hibernate-using-oracle)

---

On a Side note, `PL/SQL` Solution for the same could be like USING `RETURNING` clause with the INSERT.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  l_id t1.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (t1_seq.nextval, 'FOUR')
  RETURNING id INTO l_id;
  COMMIT;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('ID=' || l_id);
END;
/
ID=4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks Maheshwaran, Actually , i need it for hibernate generated query , which is executed before "insert into". Following is the query - "Hibernate: select BILLER_ONBOARDING_ID_SEQ.nextval from dual ", I have created another user which is passed to hibernate for doing it's transaction. so how would i execute this hibernate query as SYS.?